# How to make this specialized function work

Tags: c++, templates

Here's the deal. I've looked on this forum and I didn't find the information I'm searching for or I'm probably not able to repeat it for my problem. I have a class Table which is generic and I have a class named MyString.

```
template <typename typeGen, int DIM>
class Table {
    public:
        TableauGenerique() : index_(0) { //On initialise courant à 0
        }
        void add(typeGen type);
    private:
        typeGen tableGen_[DIM];
        int index_;    
};
```

My problem is with the add function.
 I sometimes have to do this in the main.cpp: (which works well)

```
 Table <float,6> tabFloat;
    tabFloat.add(1.6564);
```

and at one point, I need to do this which doesn't work because I need to specialize the add function to create an object of MyString, to pass it the string and then store the object in the array (tableGen) :

```
TableauGenerique <MyString,4> tabString;
```

So I tried this (after the class), without success.

```
template <typename typeGen, int DIM>
void Table<typeGen,DIM>::add(typeGen type){ //Which is the generic one for float or ints
    if(index_ < DIM) {
        tableGen_[courant_] = type;
        index_++; 
    }
}

template <class typeGen, int DIM>
void Table<typeGen,DIM>::add<string>(typeGen type) { //(line 75) Which is the specific or specialized function for myString
    MyString str(type);
    if(index_ < DIM) {
        tableGen_[courant_] = str;
        index_++; 
    }
}
```

So, How can I make this work because it doesn't compile at all, saying: line75 : error: expected initializer before '<' token and in the main it says not matching function to call Table::add(const char[6]),

I hope everything is clear enough. Let me know if somethings is unclear.

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class typeGen, int DIM>
void Table<typeGen,DIM>::add<string>(typeGen type)
```

You're trying to specialize `add()` when in fact it is not a function template to begin with. How do you expect it to work?

---

You probably meant: (specialization of the class)

```
template <int DIM>
void Table<string,DIM>::add(string type)
```

But then this is allowed only if you specialize the class itself. Without specializing the class, the above code would give compilation error!

EDIT:

You can read these online tutorials:

- [Introduction to C++ Templates](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/427)
- [14.5 — Class template specialization](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/145-class-template-specialization/)
- [Template Specialization and Partial Template Specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html)
- [Explicit specialization (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fexplicit_specialization.htm)

Comment: Oh okay, so in order to use a specialized method, we need to specialize the class? And sorry for the stupid question, but for my case, how do you explicitly specialize the class? Thanks again for your answer

Comment: @Etienne: You cannot specialize a method, if it's not a template!

Comment: Do you know a good tutorial ? I really don't understand how templates work I think...

Comment: @Etienne: I updated my answer. Go through the links, and read whatever you find easy, and you can also search in google, if you come across something which don't know, or want to explore more!

Comment: @Etienne: Dont worry. No one understands templates :) Sometimes templates can come in handy but they are rarely needed imo.

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the code of the `MyString` class, you can provide constructors that act as implicit conversions from `float` to `MyString`. An example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class MyString {
public:
  MyString(float number) {
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << number;
    value = buffer.str();
  }

  void print() {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
  }
private:
  std::string value;
};

template <class T>
class Foo {
public:
  void DoStuff(T item) {
    item.print();
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo<MyString> foo;

  foo.DoStuff(1.342); // implicitly converts float to MyString

  return 0;
}
```

This way, you do not need any specialization of the add method. However, implicit conversions are tricky, and you have be careful not to invoke them accidentally, and they may create ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Upon a second thought, my suggestion below is basically equivalent to

```
Table<MyString,4> tabString;
tabString.add(MyString("whatever"));
```

and therefore excessive and/or does not solve the problem. Feel free to ignore :)

---

I would extend the class Table with a generic method to add something from which you can construct an object of the desired type:

```
template <typename typeGen, int DIM>
class Table {
    public:
        Table() : index_(0) {}
        void add(typeGen type);
        // The additional method
        template<typename T> void add(const T& src);
    private:
        typeGen tableGen_[DIM];
        int index_;
};

template<typename typeGen, int DIM>
template<typename T>
void Table<typeGen,DIM>::add(const T& src) {
    if(index_ < DIM) {
        tableGen_[courant_] = typeGen(src);
        index_++;
    }
}
```

Note construction of a temporary typeGen object before the assignment.
Assuming that MyString object can be constructed from a string literal, i.e. from const char*, you can then use it as following:

```
Table<MyString,4> tabString;
tabString.add("whatever");
```

or if the above assumption is wrong, the following should probably work (because you constructed a MyString instance from a string instance):

```
tabString.add(string("whatever"));
```